# I have a text file and I only want to extract the numbers from each line, how do I do that?

Tags: c++

Say I have a text file of the form:

```
Re_o,41.03432927885793
Re_i,62.943980961182625
Pr,0.6311803721661048
ecc_ratio,0.052136775793810645
r_i,0.44205861426671267
```

And I only want to extract the numbers on each line in c++. How do I do that?

Comment: Seems to me you want everything *past* the `','` on each line. So read a line, discard everything up to and including the comma, then extract your value. Rinse/repeat for each line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can approach this:

You can use `std::getline()` to read each line, and use `std::istringstream` to parse each line:

```
std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
    double value;
    iss >> value;
    // use value as needed...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/VsXAaa1ZV)

Alternatively, you can parse each line manually:

```
std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inFile, line))
{
    double value = std::stod(line.substr(line.find(',')+1));
    // use value as needed...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/0eMSRqlCH)

Or, you can simply read the values directly from the `std::ifstream`, ignoring everything else you don't want:

```
std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
double value;
while (
    inFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',') &&
    inFile >> value
    )
{
    // use value as needed...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/l8KbnhQMA)